# Non Bootable system -> Ubuntu is installed fine but it doesn't boot!?

Tags: installation, boot, server, nvidia, raid

I have a Dell Dimension 3000 and I am trying to make it a web server. I have tried installing the Ubuntu server 13.04 and Ubuntu Desktop 13.04. I have had no luck.
The only thing that works is the live CD. It installs fine but it doesn't boot.
Here are the stats of the machine: Nvidia Ge-force 8400 GS 512 MB Card, two Western Digital 150 GB HDDs (IDE), Intel P4 2.66 GHz, 1GB of RAM, Intel PRO/100 VM Ethernet Connection, Acer T231H Screen VGA connection (the touch part is plugged into another computer).

Hope someone can help. :-)

Comment: Maybe the hard disk is not selcted in 'primary boot options' of BIOS!? also, please add the output if this command to your question using live mode: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: What does "doesn't boot" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Well I have installed a system with RAID 1 before (Microsoft) and it works fine. I mean that during instalation that it won't install GRUB it "can't find the disk". I think the disk is '/dev/md0' for RAID but when i got it installed. Oh and if it is RAID 1 then it doesn't matter which disk is booted from. because they are an exact copy of each other ( with some exceptions). I have checked the BIOS it is set up fine.

Comment: I have 2 HDDs (both 150GB). Here are how they are set up:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It turned out to be the lack of a /boot partiton.
i have RAID set up as such:
100MB /boot
2GB swap
and the rest of the drives are / (for root).
It now runs perfectly!